# Server-Side Application License

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I want to use Nginx, PHP and Apache Http Server on my commercial server.

Licences:

```
Nginx(http://nginx.org/LICENSE),  

Apache Http Server(https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0),      

PHP(http://php.net/license/3_01.txt).
```

Should I put a license notice on the site?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: hire a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.